# assignement from incompatible pointer type (t_file *, recoding ls)

Tags: c, warnings, ls

I've a warning saying me "assignment from incompatible pointer type" on this code when I'm trying to make a linked list of files with some details recursively :

***Main.c :***

```
t_file          *get_stat(DIR *directory)
{
  struct dirent *curfile;
  t_file        *new;
  if ((curfile = readdir(directory)) == NULL)
    return (NULL);
  new->name = curfile->d_name;
  new->rights = mls_rights(new->name); 
  new->hardlinks = mls_hl(new->name);
  new->owner = mls_owner(new->name);
  new->group = mls_group(new->name);
  new->size = mls_size(new->name);
  new->lastacctime = mls_lat(new->name);
  new->lastmodtime = mls_lmt(new->name);
  new->createtime = mls_ct(new->name);
  new->next = get_stat(directory); //assignment from incompatible pointer type
  return (new);
}
```

***mls.h :***

```
typedef struct  s_file
{
  char          *name;
  char          *rights;
  int           hardlinks;
  char          *owner;
  char          *group;
  long long     size;
  char          *lastacctime;
  char          *lastmodtime;
  char          *createtime;
  t_file        *next;
}               t_file;
```

I've search for four hours, and I've still found nothing so could you help me please.

Comment: `t_file        *next;` change to `struct  s_file  *next;`

Comment: also `new->name = curfile->d_name;` `new` is uninitialized variable.

Comment: nitpick: missing a `;` and _possibly_ something else also in `mis.h`

Comment: Thanks BLUEPIXY, the problem was the `t_file *next` in the struct.
I can't believe it was a such silly thing.